# Fortran syntax highlight

Tags: fortran, cloud9-ide

Where can I activate or use, into c9.io IDE, the Fortran syntax file highlight?
with vim O got it, but I like to use the same way the syntax into de ACE editor (is it the default editor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax highlighting for fortran yet, if you know fortran you can help to create a highlighter for ace. See http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter and http://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html